# php mysql login system issues

Tags: php, mysql

I think i am missing a small detail but I can't quite figure out what. my database is connected 100% sure of that. my register.php page loads data perfectly. when I try to set the login system I get the same echo "invalid email or password" wether I type good information or bad(just to check). at a certain point.

I changed the code to see if i could post data from my database to my page and it worked perfectly so I guess my PDO connection to the db is good. so why do I always have the same echo for both situations?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$db_server = "localhost";

$db_user = "root";

$db_password = "";

$db_name = "newsite";

try{

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
catch(PDOException $e){

        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){

$req = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,email, password FROM users_tb WHERE email= :email');

 $req->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);

 $req->execute();

 $result= $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

  if (count($result)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])){

    echo "Alleluia!";

   }else{

    echo "invalid email or password";
   }

}      
}

?>
```

the for

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        <table width="400" border="5" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Login</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></input></td>                   
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></input></td>                    
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign up"></input></td>                    
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide your form.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure the password column's length is 60+, otherwise it will fail on you silently.

Comment: check the table name you given and check the button name you given

Comment: Basic debugging tip break apart or try one portion of the if statement maybe you are not getting results or maybe the column is not password. either way narrow down what you are looking at. Also print_r or var_dumb results...

Comment: show your password_verify function may be there is mistake .what you returning there

Comment: array (size=3)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'email' => string 'kascongo@gmail.com' (length=18)
  'password' => string '0987654' (length=7)

Comment: thats the var_dump of $results it matchs the data in the db..

Comment: @jothi `password_verify` is a built in function!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `password_verify` which verifies that a password *matches a hash*.

Looking at your comments though you are not storing a hash, you are storing the actual password `0987654`.

So, when entering the password into the database you must save the result of

`password_hash("your_password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` where `your_password` is your password, rather than just storing the value such as `0987654`

Your hash should be 60 characters by default, it should look something like...

`$2a$04$PnJr5Vo/EDwbCV0z16ceyuj.z4Cw..6L/0cfFPgTCPv0un0qBp.qm`

Comment: sorry for taking so long i finally got it by changing to mysqli connection thx everyone!!!!